# Default behavior when press enter in HTML text input elements

Tags: javascript, html, cordova, google-chrome, default

I'm working on a cross-browser compatibility issue with HTML input fields.

On my Chrome 63.0, when I pressed <kbd>enter</kbd> in an input[type=text], it triggers `change` event, and no `blur` event is fired. ( I tired with this https://jsfiddle.net/agentmilindu/ekhT4/2984/ )

However, I see in some browsers, a `blur` event is triggered when pressing <kbd>enter</kbd>.

I see lot of question on StackOverflow asking how to stop triggering this `blur` event when enter is pressed,

1. [Prevent both blur and keyup events to fire after pressing enter in a textbox](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143011/prevent-both-blur-and-keyup-events-to-fire-after-pressing-enter-in-a-textbox)
2. [onkeypress + onblur in javascript](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8446788/onkeypress-onblur-in-javascript)

The app( a PhoneGap app written in React ) I'm currently investigating has a function which gets triggered by `blur` event when the user press <kbd>enter</kbd>, but in new browsers ( new phones and on my Chrom 63.0 also ) this is not working.

Now I'm confused what is the actual default behaviour when someone press <kbd>enter</kbd> in an input[type=text] filed. Should it be `change`+`blur` or only `change`? Is there any document which I can refer?

Comment: A blur event is triggered on a 'focus out' situation; I hope that much is clear; So when you hit enter, focus exits input box, thus blur gets invoked.

In ur fiddle, I didnt see blur invoked on pressing enter (m using chrome 61)

Comment: Yes, I too don't get a `blur` event when I press `enter` in the fiddle. Is that the default behaviour? But I see some getting a `blur` event too. At least the app I'm investigating is expecting a `blur` event to be trigger when `enter` key is pressed. @RajkumarSomasundaram

Comment: The [first question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11143011/prevent-both-blur-and-keyup-events-to-fire-after-pressing-enter-in-a-textbox) you linked to had this behavior because they called `alert()` inside the `change` event handler, thus making the whole page loose focus ([fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ekhT4/2985/)). The second question doesn't seem to imply the behavior your describe happen. It's a long time I read these specs, but IIRC, pressing enter in an input shouldn't not make it loose focus. So the best for you is to ask the guy who wrote that script why he did so like that.

Comment: Oh actually they possibly thought about the *next* button you've got instead of the default enter on mobile devices when the input is part of a <form>.

Comment: @Kaiido Oh, yes, maybe they thought of the `next` button on the mobile devices. But on my device, I don't see this happening and I don't see a `next` button even. :/

Comment: You need to wrap your inputs in a `<form>` element https://jsfiddle.net/ekhT4/2986/

Comment: @Kaiido my mobile device( Android O, Chrome 61.0 ) still does not take me to the next field nor trigger the `blur` event :/

Comment: Ah weird, my chrome 62 and FF 53 on Android N do both show it. Might also be dependent on the virtual keyboard used. But anyway, the default for enter is just trigger check-for-changes, and not blur by default. However, some users might indeed have this *next* button if the inputs are in a same form. But then the blur event would trigger because they did switch to a new input.

Answer (score 0):

I cant say much for apps, but for browsers; (i tried your fiddle in both chrome 61 and Firefox 55), these are my observations;

1) blur is triggered on focus out; text changes or not doesn't matter; if there is focus out, then blur triggers

2) change is triggered only if:

```
i)  text content changes within the input box changes
ii) enter key is pressed
```

either alone will not trigger change;

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

The HTML spec documents

https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/form-control-infrastructure.html#implicit-submission

say that the browser UserAgent may be set to cause the form to submit when Enter is depressed while focus is in an input "text" element.

According to:

https://www.tjvantoll.com/2013/01/01/enter-should-submit-forms-stop-messing-with-that/

```
“There are pages on the Web that are only usable 
if there is a way to implicitly submit forms, 
so user agents [browsers] are strongly encouraged 
to support this.”
```